# Javascript html decoding

Tags: javascript, asp.net, encoding, decoding

When I receive html text by ajax in asp.net application it looks like:

```
&lt;span%20style='color:green;font-weight:bold'&gt;%20Text%20Msg&lt;/span&gt;
```

how is it possible in javascript decode that text to normal html?

```
<span style='color:green;font-weight:bold'> Text Msg </span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no technical reason it should look like that - especially since it looks like some strange mixture of HTML and URL encoding which neither does JSON require. You should check you server-side script and find out why it's being encoded and turn it off.

Comment: Are you using an XSLT to generate the markup? What is generating this code?

Comment: It looks like the string is double encoded: first Html Encoded and then URL encoded. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice function here that does it for you - http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars_decode:427

Answer (score 0):

You are probably best suited with finding a server side solution as already mentioned in the comments, since this seems like a server side problem.

If you for some reason wish to do this client side anyway, here is a solution:

```
var str = "&lt;span%20style='color:green;font-weight:bold'&gt;%20Text%20Msg&lt;/span&gt;";
var fixedStr = decodeURIComponent(str).replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>');
```