# How to decode unicode HTML by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, decode

How to use JavaScript to decode from:

```
\u003cb\u003estring\u003c/b\u003e
```

to

```
<b>string</b>
```

(I searched in internet, there are some site with same question, such as:
[Javascript html decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692882/javascript-html-decoding)
or
[How to decode HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366021/how-to-decode-html-entities)
but it **dont have same encode fomat**)
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
decodeURIComponent('\u003cb\u003estring\u003c/b\u003e');

//  "<b>string</b>"
```

Edit - I would delete the above answer if I could.

The original question is a bit ambiguous.

`console.log('\u003cb\u003estring\u003c/b\u003e');` will already yield `<b>string</b>`

If the `\` characters are escaped, then a replacement method could be used to replace `\\` with just `\`, thus allowing the proper Unicode escape sequence.

Comment: Note that the string was already `<b>string</b>`. `decodeURIComponent` did nothing. http://jsfiddle.net/ZAXux/. Here's a jsfiddle to show `decodeURIComponent` does nothing when the string is literally `\u003cb\u003estring\u003c/b\u003e` http://jsfiddle.net/ZAXux/1/

Comment: @Esailija Your second jsFiddle has an extra "\" character. As for your first statement, what do you mean "does nothing"?

Comment: In javascript you need to write `"\\u"` to get `\u` literally. If you don't escape the backslash and write `"\u"` , it is interpreted as a Unicode escape sequence. By nothing I mean it doesn't do anything and it can be removed without any change as the first jsfiddle shows. So: `decodeURIComponent('\u003cb\u003estring\u003c/b\u003e'); === '\u003cb\u003estring\u003c/b\u003e'`

Comment: @Esailija You are 100% right...I feel really stupid right now. Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. I'll remove this answer.

Comment: If the string contains `\u003c` literally, then removing \ will just yield `u003c`. The escape sequences are only meaningful when something is parsing them.

Answer (score 29):

This is a dup of [How do I decode a string with escaped unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7885096/8388).  One of the answers given there should work:

```
var x = '\\u003cb\\u003estring\\u003c/b\\u003e';
JSON.parse('"' + x + '"')
```

Output:

```
'<b>string</b>'
```

Comment: Since I just happened on this again, here's a more modern version: `JSON.parse(\`"${x}"\`)`