# How to decode specific characters (unicode) in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, utf-8

I have a Sheets that contains text as `dÃ©fi` (défi) or `Ã–sterreich` (Östereeich).

I can decode the first by this script, on the other hand I am not able to do the second (I mean the code takes 3 bytes)

Thanks for any help!

```
function decode(txt){
  var texte = []
  for (i=0;i<txt.length;i++){
    var n = txt.substring(i,i+1).charCodeAt()
    if (n>127){
      if ((n & 32) > 0){
        //texte.push(decode_utf8(txt.substring(i,i+3))) ??
        i+=2
      }
      else{
        texte.push(decode_utf8(txt.substring(i,i+2)))
        i++
      }
    }
    else{
      texte.push(txt.substring(i,i+1))
    }
  }
  return (texte.join(''))
}
function decode_utf8(s) {
  return decodeURIComponent(escape(s));
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885096/how-do-i-decode-a-string-with-escaped-unicode

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15929686/how-to-decode-unicode-html-by-javascript/15929722

Comment: Could you provide expected output for the input?

Comment: @Cooper : the problem remains, how can I know \uxxxx for `Ã–` in advance since I don't know that this character coded on 3 bytes 226|128|147  is Ö / @TheMaster ; as I mentionned ...  `dÃ©fi = défi` and `Ã–sterreich = Östereeich`

Comment: I did some research to try to assist you but in reality I know very little about this sort of thing.  It's something I'd like to know more about but as yet I have not found a pressing need.

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper for all your efforts! After a night of work and research I finally solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution ... based on [github](https://gist.github.com/tudisco/309479/0943271466e3c511b7ff88567469eb5ba7d50b39)

```
function utf8decode(utftext) {
  var string = "";
  var i = 0;
  var c = c1 = c2 = 0;
  while ( i < utftext.length ) {
    c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);
    if (c < 128) {
      string += String.fromCharCode(c);
      i++;
    }
    else if((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
      c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
      string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
      i += 2;
    }
    else {
      c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+1);
      c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i+2);
      string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
      i += 3;
    }
  }
  return string;
}
```