# Unicode decode doesn't work in change listener on Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, entities

As you will see on the code below, the unicode decoder works on alert but when it comes to textarea listener, it doesn't work as expected, could you catch the problem?

```
<textarea name="" id="first" cols="75" rows="15"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="result" cols="75" rows="15"></textarea>
```

```
const jsEscape = (str) => {
  return str.replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'),"\\'");
}
const decodeUnicodeEntities = (data) => {
  return unescape(jsEscape(data));
}
alert(decodeUnicodeEntities('http://x.com\u0026shop_id=123'), 'check')
$('#first').on('change keyup paste', function() {
  $('#result').val(decodeUnicodeEntities($(this).val()));
});
```

Also live pen, https://codepen.io/RainThemes/pen/yLqgdXK

Solved with this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937764/10413531

Comment: What exactly is it that you expect your code to do?

Comment: if you run the code you will see it will give you clear url on alert, but if you put the encoded url in first textarea, it not gonna decode onto second textarea as expected, i think it's about `$(this).val()` statement

Comment: In your test case (the `alert()`), the Unicode escape in the string will be turned into "&" *before* your function is ever called; the parser will do that when it parses the string constant.

Comment: what's the way to implement this on my use case?

Comment: Note that `escape()` and `unescape()` are about URL syntax, not JavaScript string syntax. Escapes in URLs do not look like JavaScript escapes for Unicode.

Comment: but if I just put the plain string instead of `$(this).val()`, it works expected, how can I fix so

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do; you have not explained it clearly. If you would edit the question and show the kind of string that would be in the input textarea, and what you would like the output to look like, that might help.

Comment: try `alert('http://x.com\u0026shop_id=123', 'check')` your method does nothing, the string literal is already "decoded", that's why it's not working on the textareas.

Comment: well just wanna decode unicodes come from first area into the second textarea but in my case it still gives me same url

Comment: @Thomas thanks for making sharp and clear

Comment: Again, **add example input and output to the question**.  It's not clear what you're talking about.

Comment: I solved with this answer,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937764/10413531
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<textarea name="" id="first" cols="75" rows="15"></textarea>
<textarea name="" id="result" cols="75" rows="15"></textarea>
const jsEscape = (str) => {
  return str.replace(new RegExp("'", 'g'),"\\'");
}
const decodeUnicodeEntities = (data) => {
  return unescape(jsEscape(data));
}
alert(decodeUnicodeEntities('http://x.com\u0026shop_id=123'), 'check')
$('#first').on('change keyup paste', function() {
  $('#result').val($(this).val());
});
```

This will ensure that the value of #result is updated whenever the value of #first changes.

Comment: Thanks but I tried you can see here, https://codepen.io/RainThemes/pen/yLqgdXK?editors=1111 it gives me same output, just put `http://x.com\u0026shop_id=123` this the first textarea and you will see, output is same

Answer (score 0):

here are all escape sequences defined: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#escape_sequences

they're not that many and fairly straightforward to parse

```js
const decodeUnicodeEntities = (data) => data.replace(
  /(\\[0'"nrvtbf\\])|\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}|\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}|\\u\{([0-9a-fA-F]{1,6})\}/g,
  (m, a, b) => a ? JSON.parse(`"${a}"`) : String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(b || m.slice(2), 16))
);

$('#first').on('change keyup paste', function() {
  $('#result').val(decodeUnicodeEntities($(this).val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="first" cols="75" rows="15">http://x.com\u0026shop_id=123</textarea>
<textarea name="" id="result" cols="75" rows="15"></textarea>
```